# Replace string with a particular format

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I have a string with the following format,

```
 some_string%value1:value2:value3:%some_anather_string%value4:value5:value6:%
```

I need to remove`%value1:value2:value3:%` and `%value4:value5:value6:%` from the string,i mean i need to remove any string with the format of starting with `%` ending with `:%` and values seperated with `:`

Is this possible?

I try with `str_replace()`,But it work only we know the values.

Comment: You've tagged it [preg-replace], isn't that the answer?

Comment: But how to write the expression?

Comment: `%.*?%`, would match everything between (and including) `%`. Your requirements are a bit vague.

Comment: s possible to check ':' occure two times in the string? Now it checks between % and :%?

Comment: `%([^:]+?:){3}%` = three groups consisting of non-colons and ending in colons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can use this simple regex

```
echo $str = preg_replace("~%(.*?):%~","", $str);
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/141109)</kbd>

Comment: Your answer is helpful.but is possible to check  ':' occure two times in the string? Now it checks between % and :%

Comment: _Now it checks between % and :%_ , That was your question right ? Could you please elaborate and post your expected output instead ?